# FileUpload dose not return value in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have asp.net web application.asp code like below:

```
<input id="fileUpload" size="75" type="file" name="fileUpload" runat="server" />
```

also have javascript function like below:-

```
 function fnValidateFileUpload() {
    var objFileUpload = document.getElementById('<%=fileUpload.ClientID%>').value;

    if (objFileUpload.value == '') {
        alert("Please select a Microsoft Excel file to upload.");
        objFileUpload.focus();
        return false;
    }
           return true;
}
```

In page am also add attribute:-

```
btnUpload.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:return fnValidateFileUpload();");
```

On upload click button:-

```
string val = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName).ToString();
```

It gave object refferance dose not find exception.could not load path (value).

Comment: what do you want to know? Just the filename?

Comment: whole path with file name

Comment: Got the solution , I missed that i used update panel and did not add trigger for upload button so that this problem happed. Thank you for the time team....

Comment: @user3497420 So, add one solution. :)